# Why is my variable undefined in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

Here is my controller code, As soon as the function init() runs, it returns undefined for this.customers.

```
myApp.controller('OrdersController',['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
this.orders = null;


this.customers = [
    {joined: '2012-12-03', name: 'Amit', city: 'Delhi', orderTotal: 34.53,orders: [{id:1,product:'shoes',total:'34.53'}]},
    {joined: '1995-04-24', name: 'Ravi', city: 'Mumbai',orderTotal: 45.34,orders: [{id:2,product:'socks',total:'53.51'}]},
    {joined: '2003-03-21', name: 'Flish', city: 'Lonavla', orderTotal: 134.323,orders: [{id:3,product:'books',total:'43.55'}]},
    {joined: '2003-10-14', name: 'Meahe', city: 'Pune', orderTotal: 12.33,orders: [{id:4,product:'eraser',total:'12.33'}]}
];

function init() {
    console.log('infunc',this.customers);
    //search the customers for customerId
    for(var i=0; i < this.customers.length; i++){
        if(this.customers[i].orders[0].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
            this.orders = this.customers[i].orders;
        }
    }
}

init();

}]);
```

Comment: avoid using this instead use var customer or $scope.customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better define `var vm = this` then use instead of `this`.

```
myApp.controller('OrdersController',['$routeParams', function ($routeParams)        {
var vm = this; 
var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
vm.orders = null;

vm.customers = [
    {joined: '2012-12-03', name: 'Amit', city: 'Delhi', orderTotal: 34.53,orders: [{id:1,product:'shoes',total:'34.53'}]},
    {joined: '1995-04-24', name: 'Ravi', city: 'Mumbai',orderTotal: 45.34,orders: [{id:2,product:'socks',total:'53.51'}]},
    {joined: '2003-03-21', name: 'Flish', city: 'Lonavla', orderTotal: 134.323,orders: [{id:3,product:'books',total:'43.55'}]},
    {joined: '2003-10-14', name: 'Meahe', city: 'Pune', orderTotal: 12.33,orders: [{id:4,product:'eraser',total:'12.33'}]}
];

function init() {
    console.log('infunc',vm.customers);
    for (var i=0; i < vm.customers.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.customers[i].orders[0].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
            vm.orders = vm.customers[i].orders;
        }
    }
 }

  init();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically answered by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers), which explains that `this` and `$scope` are not necessarily the same thing.  When the controller is created, `this` is the controller, and so is `$scope`.  But when the function `init()` actually gets evaluated, there is no guarantee that `this` has the same meaning as `$scope`.  In any case, data stored using `this` will not be available to any view, rather only things stored to `$scope` will be available.  So for so many reasons, you should change your code to:

```
myApp.controller('OrdersController',['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
    var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
    $scope.orders = null;

    $scope.customers = [
        {joined: '2012-12-03', name: 'Amit', city: 'Delhi', orderTotal: 34.53,orders: [{id:1,product:'shoes',total:'34.53'}]},
        {joined: '1995-04-24', name: 'Ravi', city: 'Mumbai',orderTotal: 45.34,orders: [{id:2,product:'socks',total:'53.51'}]},
        {joined: '2003-03-21', name: 'Flish', city: 'Lonavla', orderTotal: 134.323,orders: [{id:3,product:'books',total:'43.55'}]},
        {joined: '2003-10-14', name: 'Meahe', city: 'Pune', orderTotal: 12.33,orders: [{id:4,product:'eraser',total:'12.33'}]}
    ];

    function init() {
        console.log('infunc',this.customers);
        for (var i=0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.customers[i].orders[0].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
                $scope.orders = $scope.customers[i].orders;
            }
        }
    }

    init();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Biegeleisen and hadiJz's responses were very helpful and contain everything you need to know, but I was in the process of responding with a general Javascript explanation and wanted to include it.  This simplified excerpt has helped me with `this` when convoluted by elements of Angular:

> Regarding Javscript in general, `this` can be bound in three different
>   ways.  `this` is bound in the local scope of the invoked function (it
>   is not a property of an object).  If a function is invoked normally
>   (e.g., f()), then 'this' points to the global object.  If a function
>   is invoked as a constructor (i.e., as part of 'new'), then 'this'
>   points to the newly created object. The last case for `this` is a method invocation (e.g., a.f()), where 'this' will point to the object that results from evaluating the left of the dot.

I'm not trying to steal the answer and you should definitely choose Tim or hadiJz's, but this may help you understand elements of their responses.